# Make specific key sticky

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I have found [enabling sticky keys under xorg (awesome desktop manager)](https://superuser.com/questions/410657/enabling-sticky-keys-under-xorg-awesome-desktop-manager) on Super User, which showed me that I can enable sticky keys via

```
xkbset sticky -twokey
```

This works as expected, but in my case I'd prefer to only make a specific key (`Alt Gr`) be sticky instead of all modifier keys. Can this be configured? And if so: where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On X11 one way to achieve that is by using XKB and making the right alt key set the current [latch mode](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node5.html#SECTION00055000000000000000) as AltGr. There are a couple of ways to go about it:

### Option 1

You can export your current keyboard layout to a file, change only the behavior of the right alt key (AltGr) and load it back to X, overriding the default layout:

1. Run `xkbcomp $DISPLAY current.xkb` to export your current keyboard layout.
2. Open the `current.xkb` file and locate the following snippet:

   ```
   key <RALT> {
       type= "ONE_LEVEL",
       symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ]
   };
   ```
3. Change it as follows:

   ```
   key <RALT> {
       type= "ONE_LEVEL",
       symbols[Group1]= [ ISO_Level3_Shift ],
       actions[Group1]= [ LatchMods(mods=AltGr) ]
   };
   ```
4. Save the file and run `xkb current.xkb $DISPLAY` to apply the new layout.

**Caveats**

1. The new layout is only good for the current X session. You'll probably want to reload it automatically after you log in. If you are using a window manager, just add `xkb current.xkb $DISPLAY` to your `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile`. If you are using a desktop environment, it might be a little trickier because DEs usually handle keyboard layouts their own way and they can override local configurations. Be sure to check their docs, or try **Option 2** below.
2. If you use multiple keyboard languages, you'll need to repeat the steps above for each exported xkb file and somehow load them when appropriate (e.g. using a shortcut for each language).

### Option 2

You can create a new XKB option that enables the desired behavior for the AltGr key and then activate it along with a language layout:

1. Create a file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` named `altgr` with the following content:

   ```
   partial alphanumeric_keys
   xkb_symbols "latch" {
       key <RALT> {
           symbols = [ ISO_Level3_Shift ],
           actions = [ LatchMods(mods=AltGr) ]
       };
   };
   ```
2. Open the `evdev` file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` and locate the line `! option  = symbols`. Add a new line after it and insert `altgr:latch = +altgr(latch)`. It will look like the following:

   ```
   ! option  = symbols
     altgr:latch = +altgr(latch)
     ...
   ```

   `+altgr(latch)` means *use the `latch` group from the `altgr` file located in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`*.

Now you need to activate the new option. You can do one of the following:

1. Run `setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option altgr:latch` to activate the new option, replacing `us` and `altgr-intl` with your language and variant. This will last for the current X session (useful for testing) and you may want to add it to `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile` so it will load automatically on login.
2. If using systemd, run `sudo localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap us pc104 altgr-intl altgr:latch` so your keyboard configuration in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` is updated.
3. If using a desktop environment, there might be a way to tell it to activate the option when loading the keyboard layout. I know GNOME uses dconf and you can set options for XKB in `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options`.

**Caveat**

XKB files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb` aren't meant to be edited directly and might get overridden when performing system updates. The "right way" to change XKB configuration is [way too complicated](https://danijozsef.medium.com/the-bazaar-with-landmines-or-how-to-extend-xkb-the-right-way-b82de59a1f9a) and I suggest you simply create a script that (re)applies the new option when needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer (especially considering this question is quite old already)!